# can I inject/insert data into a postgressql database from a openlayers 4.4 interface

Tags: javascript, postgresql, openlayers, mapserver, ogr

from an openlayers 4.4 interface I want to inject created geometries and their metadata into a postgresql database by checking that they do not already exist. is it possible through mapserver and ogr or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible directly with [UMN MapServer](https://www.mapserver.org/index.html), because it doesn't support the required WFS-T standard interface (only WFS).  You can configure [TinyOWS](https://www.mapserver.org/tinyows/) on top of MapServer to give you WFS-T capability, then you will be able to edit a PostgreSQL database through OpenLayers.